# C++: Can you iterate over a const_iterator without access to the underlying vector?

Tags: c++, c++11

I have an xml parser which returns a vector::const_iterator. I never have access to the underlying vector.

Is there a way for me to iterate over and read the values of the vector?

Comment: Not safely, unless you can also get an iterator to the end

Comment: do the docs tell you anything what you are supposed to do with that iterator?

Comment: I don't see why you can't iterate over the parsed values and read them. In regards to don't know when to stop, if you can get the end iterator like @AndyG suggested it would be great.

Comment: @PhotometricStereo: Unless you are returned an iterator to an empty vector, which OP claims to have no way of knowing.

Comment: @AndyG You're right, I neglected that case.

Comment: Well, if you get a const vector iterator, you can read it all you want, iterate as usual, but where is the end() ?

Answer (score 0):

See the code below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>


const std::vector<int> myvector = {0, 1, 1, 92, 30, 4, 5, 6};

std::vector<int>::const_iterator getIterator() {
   return myvector.cbegin();
}
int main () {

   std::cout << "myvector contains:";
   std::vector<int>::const_iterator it = getIterator();

   while (*it != 30) {
      std::cout << ' ' << *it;
      it ++;
   }
   std::cout << '\n';

   return 0;
}
```

With this code you can read the contents of a vector only through it's const_iterator.

Comment: the vector is destroyed once you hit `return`

Comment: I would rather make it  `static` in the function because now its not clear in the example why not simply use `myvector.begin` and `myvector.end` directly